# PCA on correlation matrix in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, statistics

I am trying to run a PCA on a set of normalized raster bands within ArcGIS. I would like to calculate the PCA on the correlation, not the covariance, matrix of the PCA, but Arc as far as I can tell only calculates PCs on the covariance matrix of the input bands. It seems the only fix to this is to feed the tool pre-normalized band values in the form of a z-score. I z-scored all of the input raster bands before feeding them into the Principle Components tool in Arc 10.1. The function is completing nicely, but the output is producing bands with mean values of anywhere between 9 and 34, even though they should be producing bands with a mean of 0, due to the nature of a PCA. What am I missing? Has anyone has experience with this issue before?

As requested, , here is a snapshot of my study site with a zscore raster overlaid: you can't see it well:
[image]

Here is a zoom-in to a New Jersey site showing PCA bands: [image]

Finally, here is a screenshot of the first 2 PCA band output properties:[image]

Comment: Could you tell us what the output is *supposed* to represent?  Normally the output of a principal components analysis will include the components, their eigenvalues, and ancillary information useful for interpreting the result, none of which would be raster bands.  The only thing that seems to make sense would be that these "bands" represent the principal components themselves, but normally these are standardized to unit L^2 length and typically do not have zero means.

Comment: As I understand PCAs calculated on correlation (not covariance, as Arc does unless you Z-score the values before they are input) matrices, their mean should be 0 since they are standardized around the axis and no longer include information about units, only about variation around the trend line. The value of the correlation matrix PC indicates how far away from the axis of variation the value is, but these values should all mean to 0. I believe the first PC indicates amount of water present within tidal marsh - the images I am processing are of tidal marsh along the coast. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might want to do some reading about PCA on the [stats site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pca?sort=votes).

Comment: whuber - I think we are misunderstanding each other - I just checked with 2 statisticians on my campus, and they support the content of the blurb I wrote to you re: PC scores meaning to 0 when calculated off of a correlation matrix. My question is about the black box PC tool in Arc, and if anyone has ideas about what it might be doing to generate scores not averaging to 0, even though it was fed z-scores of the original dataset. I appreciate your diligence in the matter!

Comment: I'm sure I'm misunderstanding you because I couldn't really tell what output you're referring to. It is clear you are right: PCA with any centered data is PCA in the hyperplane consisting of mean-zero values, whence all components must have zero mean. So--moving on--have you confirmed that your z-scores were computed correctly? There is a subtlety here: if there are any missing data, you must first mask all bands to the set of cells where no data are missing in any of them. Check that the means of those masked bands are zero.

Comment: I have confirmed that the Z-scores were calculated correctly. There is no missing data to my knowledge within the cells being analyzed. The raster has a lot of NoData cells, as my study area is not in the shape of a box... there is no explicit statement within the tool that NoData is NOT being processed, but I just reran the pca with an extent set within  Environments using the shape of the raster cells of interest, and still got the same output.

Comment: The tool is unlikely to make a statement like that, because the calculations for PCA can be made only with cells for which every band has a definite value.  Most statistical software will quietly drop data with missing component values, too.  Anyway, if you wish to proceed with diagnosing this situation, the next step would be to do the PCA calculations independently of ArcGIS.  This wouldn't be hard if you can get ArcGIS to output the correlation matrix, which is all that's needed.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with raster processing outside of Arc - I will try it in ERDAS and R and see what happens, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The process is easy in `R`: read the raster, run the PCA (there are several routines to do this), inspect the results.  It might be enough to do this on a small subsetted window of your image.

Comment: in the "raster" package in R I don't see a clear way to do this with a stacked raster. What am I missing?

Comment: You convert the rasters to arrays and call `prcomp` or `princomp` directly on them.

Comment: After fiddling with R for several hours, I am going to embarrass myself and ask if you have any code examples for this. I have exported each individual raster band into an ASCII file from Arc, and have tried to upload them into arc using b1=raster(file.choose()), then concatenating, then running them through a PCA, however the error "error is is.finite: default method not implemented for type "list" comes up. I have tried converting the loaded rasters into arrays and matrices using as.array and as. matrix, but it overloads R, several error messages appear saying the data files are too large.

Comment: Triumph! I subset my data by extracting z-score band values to a bunch of random points, then ran those values through princomp using princomp(SSU, cor=F) to simulate what should be happening within Arc. All of the output PC scores mean to 0. So, this tells me there is either a problem with the NAs in the raster in Arc, or something else is going wrong. Thoughts? I can't thank you enough for batting these ideas around with me, I appreciate it.

Comment: Could you perhaps post images and/or statistics of the inputs and of the ArcGIS output?

Comment: I've edited the original post with pics.

Comment: I wonder whether ArcGIS is reporting accurate statistics.  For diagnostic purposes it would help to subset your data, focusing on a truly tiny window: say a 10 by 10 region.  Does it report correct statistics for that subset?  If you perform the PCA based on that subset, does it produce the values you expect?  (Remember, you will have to re-compute the z-scores from scratch after subsetting the data and before redoing the PCA.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A quick test with a pair of random rasters is informative.**  (I *love* using random rasters because they are so useful for experimenting with and testing procedures.)  The large ones I generated had means very close to the theoretical ideal of 1/2 and standard deviations very close to the ideal of 1/sqrt(12) for uniform distributions.  Because these rasters were supposed to be independent, the principal components would be multiples of their sum and difference, suitably normalized.

After standardization (that is, converting them to their "z scores"), these two random rasters had means of zero, unit standard deviations, and extreme values close to sqrt(3) = 1.732051 in size.  Their sums and differences should therefore have a mean of zero and SD of 1.  Their extremes should be about sqrt(12/2) = sqrt(6) = 2.45 from the mean, for a total range of almost 4.90.

Instead, the two components of the output had means near 2.45, standard deviations of 1, and extremes from 0 to 4.87 (similar to the patterns shown in the question, but the question has larger means, maxima, and SDs).  These incorrect means, correct SDs, correct ranges, and exactly zero minima strongly suggest that the bands have been *additively shifted to make all their values nonnegative.*  (Asking for just one principal component does not change this: the additive shift still occurs.)

The workaround, then, is to **subtract its mean from each of the PCA bands to shift it back to a zero mean.**  As a check, the standard deviation of each band should equal the square root of its eigenvalue reported in the PCA output file.  In my test (because I computed only approximate z scores) the eigenvalues were 1.00047 and 0.99932.  Sure enough, the standard deviations reported in the `Layer Properties` dialog are 1.000234515307069 and 0.9996583939019468, respectively, and their squares agree perfectly with the eigenvalues (to the limited precision reported).

---

A quick hunt through the [ArcGIS 10.1 help pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000pq000000) produced no information at all about the PCA output.  If it cannot be found, we have to rely on tests like this to inform our understanding and hope we are correct.

Comment: this post made me look for my old university books.

Comment: @nickves I would recommend instead [searching StackExchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pca?sort=votes&pageSize=50) :-).

Comment: whuber- I compared the SDs of my subsetted PCs (produced in R) with the full PCs calculated in Arc, and they are VERY similar, which makes me agree with you in that subtracting the means from the PCs produced in Arc is a reliable work around. I am compiling the final files right now. Thank you very much for the help on this! A final question - for those having a similar issue with PCA in Arc, is there anywhere else I should post this besides here, and in ArcGIS 10.1 help? I would love to save those having similar confusion the time it takes to figure it out. Thanks again!

Comment: You could look on the [ESRI support forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/).